# What is the amount of programs for which we can solve the halting problem?

Tags: logic

The halting problem is undecidable of course.
This implies that there is at least one program for which we cannot decide whether it halts or not, because theoretically, if all we know is that the halting problem is undecidable, it could still be that there is a program that can decide for every program except itself whether it halts or not.

So I am wondering, for what percentage of programs can we solve the halting problem?
That is, if we assign a G"odel number G to every program. What is the value of the limit with respect to G to infinity of:

> s/ns

where s = the number of solvable programs with godel number 1 to G,

and ns = the number of non-solvable programs with godel number 1 to G.

Comment: There may be methods to tell if any program halts, but the same method won't work for every program. In any case the question you're asking is virtually impossible to answer with a specific number, even if it makes sense.

Comment: I am not looking for a specific answer like 75%. I am looking for an answer like: less than 0.01 % or more than 9.99%, or anything really that gives a hint at an answer. Right now I have absolutely no idea whether "almost all" programs are solvable regarding the halting problem, or the other way around.

Comment: Your question can only be answered if we agree a measure on the space of all programs. What measure do you propose?

Answer (score 1):

The question you asked is not really interesting (and I will explain why), but there is a better question.

First, notice that there are infinitely many halting programs and infinitely many programs that are indeterminable. There are obviously infinitely many halting programs because there is a Turing machine $M_k$ for every natural number $k$ that interprets the input $n$ as a number and computes $kn$; each of these halts. There are also obviously infinitely many programs that are indeterminable. For any given partial-halting-problem-solving Turing machine $H$ and each $M_k$ we can construct $M_k'$ such that $M_k'$ saves a safe copy of the input, simulates $M_k$, erases whatever $M_k$ output, then restores the original input $n$. Then $M_k'$ asks $H$ whether $M_k'$ halts on $x$. If $H$ says yes, $M_k'$ enters an infinite loop; if $H$ claims that $M_k'$ it halts and accepts the input.

Now suppose there exists some arbitrary Gödel numbering function $G$ such $G(M_0) < G(M_0') < G(M_1') < G(M_1) < G(M_2') < G(M_3') < G(M_4') < G(M_2)$. Then according to this Gödel numbering we first see one halting program and then two indeterminate, then one halting and three indeterminate, then one halting and four indeterminate; the percentage of halting programs approaches 0 in the limit as we see more and more programs.

Now suppose there exists some arbitrary Gödel numbering function $G$ such $G(M_0') < G(M_0) < G(M_1) < G(M_1') < G(M_2) < G(M_3) < G(M_4) < G(M_2')$. Then according to this Gödel numbering we first see one indeterminate program and then two halting, then one indeterminate and three halting, then one halting and four indeterminate; the percentage of halting programs approaches 100% in the limit as we see more and more programs.

It doesn't really make sense to talk about the limit of the percentage of elements of a set with some property as the size of the set goes to infinity if you don't specify the ordering. If you do specify the ordering, you need to know the relationship between the ordering and the distribution of indeterminate programs with respect to that ordering to answer this question; but if you could know that, wouldn't you be able to solve the halting problem (which is impossible)?

A more interesting question is, is there some subset of programs that have some property we can see by inspection which will guarantee that these programs will halt? If so, are there practical use cases where we can restrict ourselves to using programs with only those properties so that we know our program will halt, even though it's not possible to solve the halting problem in general? The answer is yes: there is a halting program that solves every primitive recursive function, which is roughly analogous to a computer program that uses only for loops to capture repetitive behavior and no while loops or goto jumps.